# Prevent timespan from rounding off

Tags: vb.net, timespan

I have a code that extracts duration/length of a given media file, but I have issues where its duration is rounded off to the nearest second, like 1:23:26.8 to 1:23:27, are there ways to keep it at 26 or 26.8?

```
If AVIFileInfo_Renamed(hFile, AviInfo, Len(AviInfo)) = 0 Then

   rTime = (AviInfo.dwLength / (AviInfo.dwRate / AviInfo.dwScale))
   Dim tp As TimeSpan = New TimeSpan(0, 0, rTime)
   ShowAVIInfo = tp

End If
```

Comment: what about that?

Comment: sorry, forgot to save my edit. Was going to ask if it's possible to have it at 26 or 26.8.

Comment: what you get in rTime? what's it data type? (ineteger, float,...)

Comment: it's the duration in seconds. It's long, I also tried it as decimal but still returns 1:23:27.

Comment: Nevermind, it seems the issue is with rTime being set as long, it automatically rounds it off, fixed it using Math.Floor(rTime)